# Can I search log.html file for specific keywords using Robot Framework test case?

Tags: python-3.x, automation, automated-tests, regression, robotframework

I have python code in which I use print statements to print "PASS: " and "FAIL: " pattern depending on certain conditions inside the python code. When I run my test case using Robot Framework it always declares the test case to be a PASS as the python code runs successfully. The output of the test case is saved automatically to robot framework log.html file. I see all my print statements from my python code in this log file.

What I want to achieve is, declare the robot framework test case to be a PASS or FAIL based on the pattern in log.html file. Is there a way I can search the log.html file and declare my test case to be a pass or fail accordingly? or some other solution?

**Robot Framework Calling Python Function:**

*** Test Cases ***

Establish PDX Connection

[documentation]  Check PDX database connection

Connection Request PDX Database  ${Var 1}  ${Var 2}  ${Var 3}  ${Var 4}

**Python Function: (this defines the steps for test case)**

```
def connection_request_pdx_database(server_name, database_name, trusted_connection, query):
pdx_server = TH_SQLConn()
""" Send connection request to PDX Server """
connection_request = pdx_server.connect(server_name, database_name, trusted_connection)
""" Run SQL queries """
query_pdx_server = pdx_server.query(connection_request, query)
""" Close Connection """
pdx_server.close(query_pdx_server, connection_request)
```

**Class Definition:**

```
import sys
import pyodbc


class TH_SQLConn:

def __init__(self):
    self.conn_established = True

def connect(self, server_name, database_name, trusted_connection='yes'):
    try:
        conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}; \
                                SERVER= ' + server_name + '; \
                                DATABASE=' + database_name + '; \
                                Trusted_Connection=' + trusted_connection + ';')

        if conn is not None:
            print("PASS: Connection to SQL Database is established successfully")
            return conn
        else:
            print("FAIL: Connection to SQL Database is NOT successful. Check login credentials.")
            self.conn_established = False
            # sys.exit()
    except TypeError:
        print(sys.exc_info()[0])
        print("FAIL: Connection to SQL Database is NOT successful. Check datatype of parameters passed.")
        self.conn_established = False
        # sys.exit()
    except pyodbc.OperationalError:
        print(sys.exc_info()[0])
        print("FAIL: Connection to SQL Database is NOT successful. Unable to complete login process due to delay in opening server connection.")
        self.conn_established = False
        # sys.exit()
    except:
        print(sys.exc_info()[0])
        print("FAIL: Connection to SQL Database is NOT successful.")
        self.conn_established = False
        # sys.exit()

def query(self, conn, sql_stmt):
    """
    Create the connection cursor
    Read data from the SQL database table
    """
    if self.conn_established is True:
        try:
            cursor = conn.cursor()
            cursor.execute(sql_stmt)
            # Loop through the result of SQL query
            for row in cursor:
                print(row)
            return cursor
        except AttributeError:
            print(sys.exc_info()[0])
            print("FAIL: Required parameters to run SQL query method are not available")
            self.conn_established = False
            # sys.exit()
        except pyodbc.ProgrammingError:
            print(sys.exc_info()[0])
            print("FAIL: Either the user tried to run a SQL query without establishing connection to SQL server database first.\n OR Check for SQL statement syntax error, an error is found in SQL query.")
            self.conn_established = False
            # sys.exit()
    else:
        pass

def close(self, cursor, conn):
    """
    Remove the cursor and close the connection
    """
    if self.conn_established is True:
        try:
            cursor.close()
            conn.close()
            # Query the database for a list of all databases on SQL server to check if connection is successfully closed
            cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM master.sys.databases")
        except AttributeError:
            print(sys.exc_info()[0])
            print("FAIL: Required parameters to run SQL connection close method are not available")
            self.conn_established = False
            # sys.exit()
        except TypeError:
            print(sys.exc_info()[0])
            print("FAIL: Required parameters to run SQL connection close method are not available")
            self.conn_established = False
            # sys.exit()
        except pyodbc.ProgrammingError:
            print("PASS: The connection to SQL Database is closed successfully")
        except:
            print(sys.exc_info()[0])
            print("FAIL: The connection to SQL Database is NOT closed successfully")
            self.conn_established = False
            # sys.exit()
    else:
        pass
```

Comment: Please disambiguate the term 'keyword'. Do you mean pattern or Robot Framework keyword. Please also share your code. I think there are ways for you but more details are needed to be sure.

Comment: Instead of printing `PASS` or `FAIL`, why aren't you actually causing the test case to fail with the `Fail` keyword, or calling `FAIL` in addition to printing the word `FAIL`?

Comment: https://github.com/robotframework/statuschecker might fit the bill ..

Comment: update the description of question and have included my code as well. See above.